# RoR Class vs Instance variables, and relaying a value to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, renderpartial

I have a controller "mainpage", with a correspondingly named view. The controller creates a @myLocalSuites variable, and the view includes the following line:

```
<li class="active"><%= link_to "Perforce", :action =>  'renderp4', :remote => true, :localSuites => @myLocalSuites %></a></li>
```

Routing is defined such that clicking this link_to calls renderp4.js.erb to render a partial within the mainpage view:

```
$('#MainPage').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript render "perforce_sync/perforceSync" %>')
```

where _perforceSync partial includes:

```
<%= select_tag "perforceSuites", options_for_select(*MYOPTIONSVARIABLE*), {:class => 'form-control', :size => "20", :multiple => true} %>
```

Where *MYOPTIONSVARIABLE* needs to be myLocalSuites as cascaded down from the mainpage view/controller.

Having tried everything I can think of, and failed - can someone please show how to modify the above snippets to use the required variable in the PerforceSync partial? Everything I've tried seems to produce something along the lines of:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass):
```

An example of what I've tried. I don't think I'm a million miles off, but...

```
<li class="active"><%= link_to "Perforce", :action =>  'renderp4', :remote => true, :localSuites => @myLocalSuites %></a></li>

$('#MainPage').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript render "perforce_sync/perforceSync", :suitesLocally => params[:localSuites]%>')

<%= select_tag "perforceSuites", options_for_select(params[:suitesLocally]), {:class => 'form-control', :size => "20", :multiple => true} %>
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Let me see if I have this right, you want the link to call the javascript function `$('#MainPage').replaceWith()`, and then dynamically generate the argument to this function with some data based on a select tag on the page? This will require ajax, since you will have to send the selected option(s) to the server, then use that response in your javascript code.

Comment: Ummm not quite (I don't think at least!)... The argument in question (an array of strings - @myLocalSuites) exists in the parent "mainpage" view. I want to pass this to the replaceWith, and then pass it on from there to the partial that gets rendered within mainpage, to populate the select_tag with the contents of that array...

Comment: why not just `options_for_select(@myLocalSuites)`?

Comment: That's what I had expected to work - but for some reason, the value get's lost....
`<%= puts @myLocalSuites %>
<li class="active"><%= link_to "Perforce", :action =>  'renderp4', :remote => true %></a></li>`  in the mainpage view shows the value of @myLocalSuites correctly, yet if I repeat that "puts" in the perforceSync.erb.html, it's empty...

Comment: Are you expecting the `perforceSync` partial to be rendered immediately on page load?

Comment: No - I have a navbar at the top of the mainpage, and it is one of the links on this navbar that is the above `<li>`. So on mainpage load, the browser window is mostly empty bar the navbar, but on clicking the "Perforce" entry on the navbar, it does the replaceWith - replacing an empty `<div class=container id=Mainpage>` with the contents of the partial...

Comment: Ok, you do know that you can't execute ruby code (including partials) in a web page after the page has loaded.

Comment: Hmmm.... so if prior to page load, @myLocalSuites has been populated with the Array of values... is there a logical / simple way to keep a copy of that array client-side (and pass this through to the partial for later rendering)? Or am I needing to look into AJAX (another new technology for me!). As you can undoubtedly tell, I'm fairly new here - learning as fast as I can! Im starting to get the impression that a button on my partial "refresh" - to update the select_tag on the partial is required - with this button firing off some AJAX to perform the behind the scenes fun, and get the array?

Comment: gonna write an answer, give me a min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your comment, there are two things you can do here. One way is to simply render some dynamic JS on page load, and then use javascript to show that data at a later point.

If this data however is to depend on user actions after the page has loaded, you must make another request to the server using AJAX.

The first way might look like this:

```
<script>
  var my_data = "<%= @some_data %>";   
    //@some_data could be set by the controller action for example
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('div.content_container').text(my_data);
  });
</script>
```

The second way would look like this:

```
<script>
  $('button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/some_resource/id.json',
      data: {param1: 'some_user_data'}
    }).done(function(data) {
      $('div.content_container').text(data);
    });
  });
</script>
```

The `data` option for the ajax call allows you to pass parameters back to the server, so you can send some data provided by the client. Documentation for jquery ajax is [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) if you want to see other options.

The `.done` callback gets fired when the client receives a response from the server, and the function parameter is the data returned.

Comment: Thanks Slicedpan. I think the AJAX route is gonna make most sense. Logically, when my mainpage navbar has several buttons on, it makes sense that when the user "comes back" to the Perforce page, it refreshes the select_tag contents... So I'll gratefully accept your answer for now, and leave you in peace - until I get confused to the point of banging my head against the wall with the AJAX implementation :)  THANK YOU :)